# Open AI TypeError: 'Completion' object is not subscriptable

Tags: python, openai-api

After open ai aprade the code , i cannot use the old one and keep getting the error like 'Completion' object is not subscriptable.

Could any one help me, thanks in advance!!

```py
from openai import OpenAI

client = OpenAI(
  api_key= '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',  # this is also the default, it can be omitted
)


f_prompt = "As Senior TelCom Agent at AT&T Mobility, craft 100-word conversations starting with the customer's message. Address various topics (e.g., AT&T Store info, Plans, Device Support, Internet Security, Voicemail, Promotions, Early Termination, DIRECTV, Billing, Porting). Avoid initiating service cancellation, but reveal the answer to whether the customer decided to stop using the service is {churn}."
f_sub_prompt = "{churn}"

df = data_10

for index, row in df.iterrows():
    churn = row["churn"]

    for i in range(1):  # 1 times each
        prompt = f_prompt.format(churn=churn)
        sub_prompt = f_sub_prompt.format(churn=churn)
        print(sub_prompt)


        response = client.completions.create(
            model="text-davinci-003",
            prompt=prompt,
            temperature=1,
            max_tokens=300,
            top_p=1,
            frequency_penalty=1,
            presence_penalty=0
        )

        finish_reason = response['choices'][0]['finish_reason']
        response_txt = response['choices'][0]['text']

        new_row = {
            'churn': churn,
            'prompt': prompt,
            'sub_prompt': sub_prompt,
            'response_txt': response_txt,
            'finish_reason': finish_reason}
        new_row = pd.DataFrame([new_row])
        df = pd.concat([df, new_row], axis=0, ignore_index=True)


df.to_csv("out_openai_completion.csv", index=False)
```

### no

TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
 in <cell line: 16>()
33         )
34
---> 35         finish_reason = response['choices'][0]['finish_reason']
36         response_txt = response['choices'][0]['text']
37

TypeError: 'Completion' object is not subscriptable

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It should be

response.choices[0].finish_reason

response.choices[0].text

Comment: it works for me, thanks you!!